# Is there any way to get two different results with single query based on condition?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, backend

I am trying to get two different results from single query but the problem is both conditions get applied on last query.

for example

```
$getUser = User::join('role_user','role_user.user_id','users.id')
        ->select('users.id','users.name','users.email','users.identity_status','users.email_verified_at','role_user.role_id')
        ->where('role_user.role_id',2)
        ->whereNotNull('users.email_verified_at');

$newMailUsers = $getUser->where('new_mail',0)->get();
            
$topSellingMailUsers = $getUser->where('topselling_mail',0)->get();
```

but when i checked sql query of $topSellingMailUsers i saw that both the conditions of new_mail and topselling_mail applied in $topSellingMailUsers query what i want is it should not consider mail condition in query.

how can i get two different results of $newMailUsers, $topSellingMailUsers based on both conditions separately.

Comment: @CBroe is there any way i can get two different results using single query ?

Comment: Guessing you need to put `->get();` at the end of `$getUser` query.

Comment: You can use a `orWhere` clause for `topselling_mail `, https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#or-where-clauses. But then you should make only one `get` call after you added both conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to clone Builder object to reuse it

```php
$selectFields = [
  'users.id', 
  'users.name', 
  'users.email', 
  'users.identity_status', 
  'users.email_verified_at', 
  'role_user.role_id'
];
/** @var Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder */
$getUser = User::join('role_user', 'role_user.user_id', 'users.id')
  ->select($selectFields)
  ->where('role_user.role_id', 2)
  ->whereNotNull('users.email_verified_at');

$newMailUsers = (clone $getUser)->where('new_mail', 0)->get();

$topSellingMailUsers = (clone $getUser)->where('topselling_mail', 0)->get();
```

Comment: Explaining why this is the case might make your answer more helpful.

Comment: @miken32 tbh i don't actually remember why Builder object changing on adding clauses on it, found it a few years ago and just remembered this fact as i often work with laravel

Comment: It's because object assignments are always done by reference. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Answer (score 1):

Every time you use `where()` method you are mutating `$getUser` query builder.

You can chain your query builder with `clone()` method and this will return another query builder with the same properties.

```
$getUser = User::join('role_user','role_user.user_id','users.id')
        ->select('users.id','users.name','users.email','users.identity_status','users.email_verified_at','role_user.role_id')
        ->where('role_user.role_id',2)
        ->whereNotNull('users.email_verified_at');

$newMailUsers = $getUser->clone()->where('new_mail',0)->get();
            
$topSellingMailUsers = $getUser->clone()->where('topselling_mail',0)->get();
```

Comment: cool...Thanks i didn;t know about this clone thing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have relations set up on models will be easier, but still can do it:

```
// Let's say you pass sometimes the role_id
$role_id = $request->role_id ?? null;
        
$getUser = User::join('role_user','role_user.user_id','users.id')
   ->select('users.id','users.name','users.email','users.identity_status','users.email_verified_at','role_user.role_id')
   // ->where('role_user.role_id',2) // replaced with ->when() method
   ->when($role_id, function ($query) use ($role_id){
       $query->where('role_user.role_id', $role_id);
   })
   ->whereNotNull('users.email_verified_at');
```

This way it will return users with ALL ROLES or if ->when(condition is TRUE)  it will return users with the role id = $role_id.

You can use multiple ->when(condition, function(){});

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of firing multiple queries you can do it in a single query as well by using collection method as like below.

```
$users = User::join('role_user','role_user.user_id','users.id')
    ->select('users.id','users.name','users.email','users.identity_status','users.email_verified_at','role_user.role_id', 'new_mail', 'topselling_mail')
    ->where('role_user.role_id',2)
    ->where(function($query) {
       $query->where('new_mail', 0)->orWhere('topselling_mail', 0);
    })
    ->whereNotNull('users.email_verified_at')
    ->get();

$newMailUsers = $users->where('new_mail',0)->get();
        
$topSellingMailUsers = $user->where('topselling_mail',0)->get();
```